Not able to compile PG16 with custom flags in freebsd 14.1 - GCC fatal error cannot read spec file
Hi everyone I am trying to install Postgresql 16 on my freebsd 14.1 hosted in an ec2 machine on AWS.
I am using GCC13 to compile the binaries and I keep on running into
gcc13: fatal error: cannot read spec file './specs': Is a directory
here is the code of my bash script
I have also uploaded the same code in github gist :- https://gist.github.com/mokshchadha/6c5590e339959a91dc6985b96dee25cb
#!/bin/sh

# Configuration variables
POSTGRES_VERSION="16.3"
POSTGRES_PREFIX="/usr/local/pgsql"
DATA_DIR="$POSTGRES_PREFIX/data"
LOGFILE="$POSTGRES_PREFIX/logfile"
BUILD_DIR="/tmp/postgresql-build"
PYTHON3_PATH=$(which python3)

# Helper functions
error_exit() {
    echo "Error: $1" >&2
    cleanup
    exit 1
}

warning_message() {
    echo "Warning: $1" >&2
}

cleanup() {
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    [ -d "$BUILD_DIR" ] && rm -rf "$BUILD_DIR" || warning_message "Failed to remove build directory."
}

check_prerequisites() {
    # Check for GCC 13
    if ! command -v gcc13 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "GCC 13 is not installed. Installing GCC 13..."
        pkg install -y gcc13 || error_exit "Failed to install GCC 13. Please install it manually using 'pkg install gcc13'."
    else
        echo "GCC 13 is installed. Checking version and configuration..."
        gcc13 --version
        gcc13 -v 2>&1 | grep "Configured with"
        
        # Check for specs file issue
        GCC_LIBDIR="/usr/local/lib/gcc13"
        SPECS_FILE="$GCC_LIBDIR/specs"
        
        if [ ! -f "$SPECS_FILE" ]; then
            echo "specs file not found. Attempting to create..."
            if ! gcc13 -dumpspecs > "$SPECS_FILE" 2>/dev/null; then
                error_exit "Failed to create specs file. Please check GCC 13 installation."
            fi
        fi
        
        # Verify GCC functionality
        if ! gcc13 -v >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            error_exit "GCC 13 is not functioning correctly. Please check your GCC installation."
        fi
    fi

    # Check for GNU Make
    if ! command -v gmake >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "GNU Make is not installed. Installing GNU Make..."
        pkg install -y gmake || error_exit "Failed to install GNU Make. Please install it manually using 'pkg install gmake'."
    fi
    
    command -v fetch >/dev/null 2>&1 || error_exit "fetch is required but not installed. Please install it using 'pkg install fetch'."
    command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 || error_exit "Python3 is required but not installed. Please install it using 'pkg install python3'."
    command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 || error_exit "OpenSSL is required but not installed. Please install it using 'pkg install openssl'."
    
    # Check for pkg-config
    if ! command -v pkg-config >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "pkg-config is not installed. Installing pkg-config..."
        pkg install -y pkgconf || error_exit "Failed to install pkg-config. Please install it manually using 'pkg install pkgconf'."
    fi
    
    # Check for LZ4
    if ! pkg info -e liblz4 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "LZ4 is not installed. Installing LZ4..."
        pkg install -y liblz4 || error_exit "Failed to install LZ4. Please install it manually using 'pkg install liblz4'."
    fi
    
    # Verify LZ4 installation
    if ! pkg-config --exists liblz4; then
        error_exit "LZ4 library not found by pkg-config. Please check your LZ4 installation."
    fi
    
    # Check for ICU
    if ! pkg info -e icu >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "ICU is not installed. Installing ICU..."
        pkg install -y icu || error_exit "Failed to install ICU. Please install it manually using 'pkg install icu'."
    fi
    
    # Verify ICU installation
    if [ -f /usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so ]; then
        echo "ICU library found at /usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so"
    else
        error_exit "ICU library not found at expected location. Please check your ICU installation."
    fi
    
    # Print ICU version
    echo "ICU version:"
    pkg info icu | grep Version
    
    # Print LZ4 version
    echo "LZ4 version:"
    pkg info liblz4 | grep Version
}

ensure_install_directory() {
    if [ ! -d "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" || error_exit "Failed to create installation directory."
    elif [ ! -w "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" ]; then
        chmod u+w "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" || error_exit "Failed to set permissions on installation directory."
    fi
}

create_postgres_user() {
    if ! pw groupshow postgres >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Creating 'postgres' group..."
        pw groupadd postgres || error_exit "Failed to create 'postgres' group."
    fi

    if ! pw usershow postgres >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Creating 'postgres' user..."
        pw useradd postgres -g postgres -m -s /usr/local/bin/bash || error_exit "Failed to create 'postgres' user."
    else
        echo "'postgres' user already exists."
    fi
}

download_postgresql() {
    echo "Downloading PostgreSQL $POSTGRES_VERSION..."
    mkdir -p "$BUILD_DIR" || error_exit "Failed to create build directory."
    cd "$BUILD_DIR" || error_exit "Failed to enter build directory."

    if [ ! -f "postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.tar.bz2" ]; then
        fetch "https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v$POSTGRES_VERSION/postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.tar.bz2" || error_exit "Failed to download PostgreSQL source."
    else
        echo "Source tarball already exists, skipping download."
    fi

    if [ ! -d "postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION" ]; then
        tar -xvf "postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.tar.bz2" || error_exit "Failed to extract PostgreSQL source."
    else
        echo "Source directory already exists, skipping extraction."
    fi

    cd "postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION" || error_exit "Failed to enter PostgreSQL source directory."
}

configure_postgresql() {
    echo "Configuring PostgreSQL with custom options..."
    PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$($PYTHON3_PATH -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())")
    PYTHON_LIB_DIR=$($PYTHON3_PATH -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var; print(get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")

    # Add ICU library and include paths
    ICU_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata"
    ICU_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"

    # Add LZ4 library and include paths
    LZ4_LIBS=$(pkg-config --libs liblz4)
    LZ4_CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags liblz4)

    export CC=gcc13
    export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -L$PYTHON_LIB_DIR $ICU_LIBS $LZ4_LIBS"
    export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I$PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR $ICU_CFLAGS $LZ4_CFLAGS"
    export ICU_LIBS
    export ICU_CFLAGS
    export LZ4_LIBS
    export LZ4_CFLAGS
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

    config_command="./configure \
        CC=gcc13 \
        --prefix=\"$POSTGRES_PREFIX\" \
        --with-blocksize=32 \
        --with-segsize=8 \
        --with-openssl \
        --with-ssl=openssl \
        --with-lz4 \
        --with-python \
        --with-icu \
        --with-includes=\"/usr/local/include $PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR\" \
        --with-libraries=\"/usr/local/lib $PYTHON_LIB_DIR\""
    echo "Configuration command: $config_command"
    echo "LDFLAGS: $LDFLAGS"
    echo "CPPFLAGS: $CPPFLAGS"
    echo "ICU_LIBS: $ICU_LIBS"
    echo "ICU_CFLAGS: $ICU_CFLAGS"
    echo "LZ4_LIBS: $LZ4_LIBS"
    echo "LZ4_CFLAGS: $LZ4_CFLAGS"
    echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    echo "LIBRARY_PATH: $LIBRARY_PATH"
    echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH: $PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
    
    # Run configure and capture output
    if ! eval $config_command > configure_output.log 2>&1; then
        echo "Configuration failed. Last 50 lines of output:"
        tail -n 50 configure_output.log
        error_exit "Configuration failed. See configure_output.log for details."
    fi
}

verify_compilation_options() {
    echo "Verifying compilation options..."
    grep -E "BLCKSZ|RELSEG_SIZE" src/include/pg_config.h
}

compile_postgresql() {
    echo "Compiling PostgreSQL..."
    gmake || error_exit "Compilation failed."
    
    echo "Compiling contrib modules (including pg_trgm)..."
    cd contrib || error_exit "Failed to enter contrib directory."
    gmake || error_exit "Compilation of contrib modules failed."
    
    cd .. || error_exit "Failed to return to main PostgreSQL directory."
    verify_compilation_options
}

install_postgresql() {
    echo "Installing PostgreSQL..."
    gmake install || error_exit "Installation failed."
    
    echo "Installing contrib modules (including pg_trgm)..."
    cd contrib || error_exit "Failed to enter contrib directory."
    gmake install || error_exit "Installation of contrib modules failed."
    
    cd .. || error_exit "Failed to return to main PostgreSQL directory."
}

setup_environment() {
    echo "Setting up environment variables..."
    if ! grep -q "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin" /etc/profile; then
        echo "export PATH=\"$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin:\$PATH\"" >> /etc/profile || warning_message "Failed to update /etc/profile."
        . /etc/profile || warning_message "Failed to source /etc/profile."
    else
        echo "PATH already includes $POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin."
    fi
}

initialize_database() {
    echo "Initializing the PostgreSQL database..."
    mkdir -p "$DATA_DIR" || error_exit "Failed to create data directory."
    chown postgres:postgres "$DATA_DIR"
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/initdb -D $DATA_DIR" || error_exit "Database initialization failed."
}

create_extension_pg_trgm() {
    echo "Creating pg_trgm extension..."
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/psql -d postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;'" || warning_message "Failed to create pg_trgm extension. You may need to create it manually in your databases."
}

start_postgresql() {
    echo "Starting PostgreSQL..."
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/pg_ctl -D $DATA_DIR -l $LOGFILE -w start"
    sleep 5  # Give the server a moment to start up
    if ! su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/pg_isready -q"; then
        check_log_file
        error_exit "Failed to start PostgreSQL."
    fi
    echo "PostgreSQL started successfully."
}

check_log_file() {
    echo "Checking PostgreSQL log file for errors..."
    if [ -f "$LOGFILE" ]; then
        tail -n 50 "$LOGFILE"
    else
        echo "Log file not found at $LOGFILE"
    fi
}

verify_custom_options() {
    echo "Verifying custom build options..."
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/psql -d postgres -c \"SHOW block_size;\"" || warning_message "Failed to verify block size."
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/psql -d postgres -c \"SHOW segment_size;\"" || warning_message "Failed to verify segment size."
    echo "Checking PostgreSQL version and compile-time options:"
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/postgres -V"
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/pg_config --configure"
    
    echo "Verifying pg_trgm extension installation:"
    su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/psql -d postgres -c \"SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'pg_trgm';\"" || warning_message "Failed to verify pg_trgm extension."
}

stop_postgresql() {
    echo "Stopping PostgreSQL..."
    if command -v "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/pg_ctl" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        su -m postgres -c "$POSTGRES_PREFIX/bin/pg_ctl -D $DATA_DIR stop -m fast" || warning_message "Failed to stop PostgreSQL."
    else
        echo "pg_ctl command not found; assuming PostgreSQL is not running."
    fi
}

uninstall_postgresql() {
    echo "Uninstalling PostgreSQL..."
    stop_postgresql
    if [ -d "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" ]; then
        rm -rf "$POSTGRES_PREFIX" || warning_message "Failed to remove PostgreSQL directories."
        echo "PostgreSQL uninstalled successfully."
    else
        echo "No PostgreSQL installation detected."
    fi
}

perform_installation() {
    check_prerequisites
    create_postgres_user
    ensure_install_directory
    download_postgresql
    configure_postgresql
    compile_postgresql
    install_postgresql
    setup_environment
    initialize_database
    start_postgresql
    create_extension_pg_trgm
    check_log_file
    verify_custom_options
    echo "PostgreSQL installed and configured successfully with pg_trgm extension!"
}

# Ensure cleanup happens on script exit
trap cleanup EXIT

# Main function
case "$1" in
    stop)
        stop_postgresql
        ;;
    uninstall)
        uninstall_postgresql
        ;;
    install)
        perform_installation
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {install|stop|uninstall}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac


why not use ports or a custom port?

./specs is a directory, you are trying to write to is as a file, just as the error message says.
